# Cannot assign a payer_id when saving a card to the vault

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-vault

According to the rest api documentation it is recommended to assign a payer_id when saving a card to the vault.

My problem is that there is no payer_id property to populate for the creditCard object in the first place.

```
creditCard.number       = "4417119669820331";
creditCard.expire_month = "11";
creditCard.expire_year  = "2018";
creditCard.first_name   = "Joe";
creditCard.last_name    = "Shopper";
creditCard.type         = "visa";
**creditCard.payer_id = "123456789";**
```

As far as I am aware I am using the latest APIs updated by Nuget in VS2012.

Comment: This is Jason with PayPal. It looks like this property got removed when we updated the `CreditCard` object to reflect the current REST schema (we have internal scripts that take in the vault schemas to generate the .NET classes).  We should never be removing properties, and the current state of the object is out-of-sync with the public documentation. The develop branch for the SDK has been updated to include this property again, and I've reached out to the API team to find out why this was removed. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. :)

Comment: Here's the link to the develop branch with the property added: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Source/SDK/Api/CreditCard.cs#L72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the response from the PayPal Vault API team:

> The `payer_id` field was never removed. We've intended to deprecate/discourage its use because we determined that this field was misleading in the way it was named - it was being mistaken for a PayPal's internal identifier, where in reality, to PayPal, it was just an arbitrary  string, intending to identify an externally managed customer id. The Vault team has since added a field named `external_customer_id` that better captures the intent.

The `external_customer_id` property (found [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Source/SDK/Api/CreditCard.cs#L72) in the current version of the SDK) is what should be used instead.  However, since the `payer_id` property will continue to be supported in the v1 version of the Vault REST services, the .NET SDK will continue to provide support for this (the upcoming v1.1 .NET SDK release will include it again).

The PayPal documentation team is working on getting the public documentation for the [credit card object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#creditcard-object) updated to include this information.

---

For future reference by other developers who may find this post, I'd like to add that if you do find a property missing from the PayPal .NET SDK, a better place to report this is to [open an issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues) on the [PayPal .NET SDK GitHub repository](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) where the code for the SDK resides.